Kolmogorov complexity bound on the prime numbers
This is an advancement of a proof concerning prime numbers, as discussed in the short introduction to Kolmogorov complexity. Unfortunately it has an error somewhere I cannnot see, as it contradicts the prime number theorem. I would appreciate any comments; say whether this approach seems misguided, and whether, maybe, I get some definition completely wrong and the argument collapses. Thanks in advance!
Definition 1: Let $M$ be a Turing Machine that takes as input a triple $(i, e, x) \in \mathbb{N}^3$, . $M$, when simulated with input $(i, e, x)$ where $p_i^e$ divides $n$ $ $  and  $x = \frac{n}{p_i^e}$, outputs an integer $n$ such that, where $p_i$ denotes the $i$-th prime number.
Algorithm for $M$:

Determine $p_i$, the $i$-th prime number.
Compute $n =   p_i^e \cdot x$

Definition 2: Let $K(n)$ denote the Kolmogorov complexity of $n$.
Lemma 1: $K(n)$ is bounded above by the length of the a self-delimiting description of $n$, let it be the one given by the above algorithm to output $n$:
$2\log\log{|M|}\  + \log{|M|}\  + 2\log\log{i}\  + \log{i}\  + 2\log\log{e}\  + \log{e}\  + \log\frac{n}{p_i^e}$
where:

$2\log\log(M)$: Complexity of delimiting the input size (used to declare the number of bits of $M$ the description of the program described).
$\log(M)$: Complexity of specifying $M$.
$2\log\log(i)$: Complexity of delimiting the input (used to declare the number of bits of $i$).
$\log(i)$: Complexity of specifying the index $i$.
$2\log\log(e)$: Complexity of delimiting the input (used to declare the number of bits of $e$)
$\log(e)$: Complexity of specifying the index $e$.
$\log\left(\frac{n}{p_i}\right)$: Complexity of specifying the quotient $\frac{n}{p_i}$.

These get passed as input to a Universal Turing Machine of our choice on which the Kolmogorov complexity definition depends on.
Assumption 1: Let $n$ be chosen such that $K(n) = \lceil\log{n}\rceil - C$, where $C$ is a constant independent of $n$.
Proposition 1: The following inequality holds:
$\log{n} - C \leq 2\log\log{M} + \log{M} + 2\log\log{i} + \log{i} + 2\log\log{e} + \log{e} + \log\frac{n}{p_i^e}$
where $2\log\log{M} + \log{M}$ is a constant independent of $n$, representing the length of the program $M$.
Corollary 1: By algebraic manipulation of Proposition 1, we obtain:
$\log{(p_i^e)} \leq k + 2\log\log{i} + \log{i} + 2\log\log{e} + \log{e}$
where $k$ is a constant.
Corollary 2: Exponentiating both sides of Corollary 1 yields:
$p_i^e \leq K \cdot e \cdot (\log{e})^2 \cdot i \cdot (\log{i})^2$
where $K$ is a constant.
Theorem 1 (Prime Number Theorem): As $i \to \infty$, $p_i \sim i \log i$.
Observation: Corollary 2 appears to contradict Theorem 1, suggesting a potential issue in my initial assumptions or reasoning.
Theorem 2 (Prevalence of High Kolmogorov Complexity): For any positive integer $C$, there exist more than $2^n(1 - 2^{-C})$ binary strings of length $n$ with Kolmogorov complexity $K(s) \geq n - C$.
Lemma 2: Binary integer having length $n$ is equivelant to a string of length $n$ and its most significant bit equal to $1$, and the Kolmogorov complexity of these representations is bigger or equal by at most a small constant from the kolmogorov complexity of the length-($n-1$) string following the $1$ (most signifificant bit of the 'number' string).
It is a standard result that;
For any $C$ there are more than $2^n \left(1 - \frac{1}{2^C}\right)$ strings (not numbers!) of length $n$ with Kolmogorov complexity $K(s) \geq n - C$.
which, after substituting string with the binary number definition, yields
Corollary 3: For any positive integer $C$, there exist more than $2^{n-1}(1 - 2^{-C}) = 2^n \cdot \frac{1}{2}(1 - 2^{-C})$ integers $n$ of integer length $\lceil \log{n}\rceil$ written in string form as $s$ with Kolmogorov complexity $K(s) \geq \lceil \log{n}\rceil - (C+1)$.
Conclusion: A significant proportion of integers of a given length have Kolmogorov complexity within a constant of their length, approaching exponentially fast 50% as $C$ increases. So there are enough such $n$ used in the above contradictory proof.
Important Note;

With $\log$ I denote the logarithm of base-2. Also, I replaced $\lceil \log{\frac{n}    {p_i^e}}\rceil=\log{\frac{n}{p_i^e}} +(something\in (0,1) )$ since the end result would be the  same jus the constant $K$ would be a little bigger

integer length of 0011 is 2 but string length is 4 that is why I differentiate between number and string. The author of the original argument  doesn't make the distinction and assumes there is an integer which string length and integer length are equal and is kolmogorov random.


Question
Is this proof problematic and at which point? I am not a trained mathematician and new to this field so I am in a state of oblivion, but I would be interested to pursue this mathematical method further.

You say that 50% is enough $n$ to get a contradiction, but it is not.
Most numbers are squarefree. It is a classical fact that the number of squarefree numbers less than $n$ is asymptotically $\frac{6}{\pi^2}n$, or slightly more than 60%, see the references in OEIS A013928.
So it is completely possible that you will not be able to do this trick with $e > 1$.

So this is an argument that all (?) kolmogorov random-enough numbers are squarefree (using e=1 and e=2 with a bound $p_i>>\sqrt{i\log{i}}$. Also from Erdos-Kac I think we conclude that their number of prime factors is very close to $\log\log{n}$. So then we can use a simular argument to place bounds on the kolmogorov complexity and distribution of the indices of their prime factors.

Yes, looks like Kolmogorov random number must be squarefree

It still seems a bit counterintuive, because, correct me If I'm wrong, wouldn't then $K(n)\approx \log{n}\approx \text{delimited_size_of}{ i_0, { \Delta{i}}} $ for most kolmogorov random enough numbers n (because we can produce $n$ by a program (it doesn't depend on $n$) with input a delimited string representing the set of the indices of the prime divisors of n), I would guess the later set can't get that big, I am writing some code to test this.

I run the code and plotted the distributions to visualize the outcome. I multiplied primes taken randomly from a range and accepted their product only if it was within a constant multiple of the primorial (product of all primes up to that range. It find that the set involving $i$ is mostly $0.6$ to $0.8$ times (here lie the most values) the binary length of the product so not $1$. The way I delimited the $i$ set was by placing headers before headers of the elements (if the would result in a decrease in the total length), where a header has value equal to the length of the next header.

I realized the outcome is not really random, because it is biased in favor of small prime indices, as I could have used bigger indexed primes, because for example I could have used $p_{ab}$ instead of the (larger)  $p_a p_b$ to make the $i$ set bigger.
